# segmentation of characters row using Horizontal histogram profile

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, image-segmentation

i want to **segment the horizontal row of characters from a image** as shown in the image

[image: input image that i have taken]
[image: histogram of taken image]

```
clear all;
cd('C:\Users\IFIM\Desktop\New folder\KANND_HAND_SET');
myFolder = 'C:\Users\IFIM\Desktop\segment';
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.bmp','Select image to be read.');
i= imread(fullfile(pathname,filename));
i=padarray(i,[0 10]);
verticalProjection = sum(i, 1);
set(gcf, 'Name', 'DEMO BY SOUMYADEEP', 'NumberTitle', 'Off') 
subplot(2, 2, 1);imshow(i); 
subplot(2,2,3);
plot(verticalProjection, 'b-');
grid on;
t = verticalProjection;
t(t==0) = inf;
mayukh=min(t)
% 0 where there is background, 1 where there are letters
letterLocations = verticalProjection > mayukh; 
% Find Rising and falling edges
d = diff(letterLocations);
startingColumns = find(d>0);
endingColumns = find(d<0);
% Extract each region
y=1;
for k = 1 : length(startingColumns)
  % Get sub image of just one character...
  subImage = i(:, startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k)); 
[L,num] = bwlabel(subImage);
for z= 1 : num
bw= ismember( L, z);
% Construct filename for this particular image.
baseFileName = sprintf('curvedimage %d.png', y);
 y=y+1;
% Prepend the folder to make the full file name.
fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
% Do the write to disk.
imwrite(bw, fullFileName);
subplot(2,2,4);
pause(2);
imshow(bw);
end;
y=y+1;
end;
```

in this code  the vertical segmentation is happening but what i want is to get the horizontal lines from the paragraph so that this vertical segmentation will done after please help 
thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

You need first to clean a little bit your image in order to simplify things. Try the following approach:

1. Small [opening](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) (delete the small isolated components). [Result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/0VRhO_Opening.png)
2. Small [closing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html) (reconnect the close components). [Result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/0VRhO_Closing.png)
3. (optional) Connected components labeling in order to separate each letter (you will certainly need it later)
4. Then, you can use the histogram projection which is going to be much easier to analyze. You should see as many peaks as rows in your signal.
5. (optional) If the histogram is not clean enough, use a median filter coupled with a gaussian filter in order to denoise and smooth your signal.

Comment: please update this code as according to you because i don't understanding what are you telling me to do properly

Comment: I've added links to the MatLab operations and links to the results.

Comment: thanks sir for helping me to remove errors from image but what i want is to segment the horizontal lines from the handwritten characters image as i uploaded the code this is for vertical   segmentation please help me to make changes in the above code so that it can be useful for cropping lines as well

Comment: First, compute the horizontal histogram on the images I have preprocessed. You will see that the histogram is much cleaner. In fact, the only moment the histogram is not null is because of the lines you are looking for.

Comment: sir i am getting the clean histogram i am editing my question as according to this will you please help me correct this code as according to my image???

Comment: I don't use MatLab, so I cannot help you with the code. But now that the histogram is clean, make it binary (0 or 1), and everywhere the histogram goes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0, that you top/bottom of each line.